# Error conexión api server

Tags: laravel, android-studio, api, flutter

Hola me sale un error en la api al poner mi sitio d prueba en la base_url[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] no tengo idea como poder solucionarlo ni dónde tengo que revisar. Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias

Cuando ingreso la URL del sitio para que conecte con la aplicación me sale el error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

He resuelto el problema de la api del servidor cambiando  localhost por la ip. Pero ahora se me presento que se queda en el splash screen. El logcat me arroja[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que el error está en esta parte del controlador, pero nose porque.

```
Future<bool> getConfigData() async {

hasConnection = true; Response response await splashRepo.getConfigData(); bool isSuccess false; if(response.statusCode 200) { _configModel ConfigModel.fromJson(response.body); isSuccess true;

}else {

ApiChecker.checkApi(response); if (response.statusText ApiClient.noInternetMessage) { hasConnection false;

isSuccess false; 
} update(); return _isSuccess; }
```

Alguien que me eche una mano. Gracias

Comment: Reinicia el router o activa la wifi o los datos de tu móvil, pues no tienes internet segun ese mensaje tan críptico (y no me extraña, creo que lo tienes un poco roto aparentemente)

Comment: Hola gracias por tu comentario, pero no es un error de internet ya lo he verificado. Estoy conectado al wifi. Jajaja es un teléfono que tengo para pruebas.

Comment: Bueno, tenia que advertirte por si lo que parecia obvio no lo era tanto para tí :-)  Seguro que navegas pues?  seguro seguro seguro?  pues entonces nada, me callo pues no se ayudarte con tan poca información que provees en la pregunta.  Suerte!

Comment: Ahí edite la pregunta para que sea un poco más entendible pero no sabría cómo más ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Tu sitio de prueba es "localhost"?  Si es así entonces alli tienes el error, pues **localhost** siempre apunta al propio dispositivo que ejecuta el código, es decir, a si mismo.  Mira de poner la IP en lugar del **localhost** o un nombre de dominio si lo tiene.

Comment: Si es localhost. Ok lo intentaré con otro y te comento. Gracias

Comment: Es posible que esté equivocado, ojo, desconozco android y flutter, pero si lo que intentas es conectar esa app con un servidor de tu red casera (o de un VPS o hosting) que esta corriendo laravel para servir esa API, entiendo que lo que debes decirle a la app es la IP donde esta ese servidor realmente (y no localhost), y tengo mis dudas que ese BASE_URL sea el codigo de una app, sino más bien del propio laravel, y entonces podria ser correcta. Lo siento, quizás te he liado más que ayudado... me callo y me voy a  sentar en el rincón de pensar (eso me pasa por graciosillo, je). Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Debes poner el servidor a escuchar por la IP de la LAN, es decir, algo como 192.168.....

Luego, cambiar la BASE_URL por la ip de ese servidor. El localhost en tu caso es la dirección de loopback de tu teléfono y por eso no encuentra el servidor.